# Mesos not offering disk in its offers

Tags: distributed-computing, mesos, distributed-system, mesosphere

I have been using Mesos for over a year now but recently got this issue where mesos doesn't include disk resource in a lot of its offers (the slave/host does register 140GB of disk when it registers with mesos master). Is that something expected? Shouldn't mesos always offer disk if the host has some available?
It does offer disk for some offers though.

Comment: it is hard to debug the issue with the information give :-).

Some Pointer/ideas:

Can you check from the Mesos UI whether there is free, unoffered disk space?
Which framework are you using? Could it be your framework is either declining offers with a filter? Or it does not decline offers and hence collects available disk without starting tasks on them?
If that doesn't help would it be possible to share some Mesos Master logs?

THX!

Comment: Thanks js84. I think it was due to the slaves holding resources. I am surprised though. I thought that mesos offered the same resource to multiple frameworks and would cancel the offer to the other framework as soon as one of them accepted it. To clarify it, lets say if resource r1 is offered to both framework f1 and framework f2. My understanding is that as soon as f2 accepts offer r1, mesos would cancel offer r1 from f1.